# Apply CSS style/class to div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some div elements
The structure is

```
<div id="comment">  
  <div id="m1">...</div>  
  <div id="m2">...</div>  
</div>
```

I want to apply some CSS or Class to the even/odd inner div of comments (or to the m1/m2 div)
So i coded this, but it did not worked :(

```
$("div>div:even").addClass("evn");
```

What i'm missing ?

Comment: Most likely you need to put this inside a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Comment: i did not used the ready mentioned above but i've included jquery.js and other jquery functions works fine too !

Comment: Why don't you put your jQuery in that document ready?

Comment: @BoltClock u r right, i think the missing ready was creating trouble !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:even` and `:odd` are 0-indexed, and may not produce results you're looking for. The first element is number 0, and that's even, so it gets selected by `:even`, rather than the second one.

For 1-indexing, you're missing the [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector):

```
$("div > div:nth-child(even)").addClass("evn");
```

Make sure that you spelled the class name correctly too, I don't know if your CSS defines an `.evn` class...

Answer (score 1):

[This link can help you to solve your proble](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/different-color-alternate-row-jquery.html)

First , define the tables and div as shown below in the “index.html” file,

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>Michael</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Sam</td></tr>
  <tr><td>John</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Jason</td></tr>
</table>
 <div>Michael</div>
 <div>Sam</div>
 <div>John</div>
 <div>Jason</div>
```

Now, we need to write the script for displaying the different color in the alternate row,

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //for div
  $("div:odd").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
  $("div:even").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");
  //for table row
  $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
  $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");
});
</script>
```

The filters “even” and “odd” can be used in jQuery for selecting odd or even index of the elements.As you can see above the background color of the odd and even “div” are changed using the “css” method and “odd” and “even” filters of jQuery and the same applies for the even and odd “tr” which means for the row of table.

Comment: dude, links to blog posts or docs make bad answers to questions. Provide your input and help him solve his specific problem.